# UILabel in UITableViewCell overflows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UILabel inside a UITableViewCell and I was trying to adjust the height, however when the height is greater than the cell height it overflows to the next cell below it. How can I avoid this? I am adding this into my contentView:

```
 [self.contentView addSubview:self.commentsText_];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to hide the overflows.

```
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or you may want to layout by overwriting at

```
- (void)setNeedsLayout
{
    [super setNeedsLayout];
    self.commentsText_.frame = .... // layout your label
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using following code you can calculate height of label and also change the height of cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

    UILabel *yourlabel;// use your memober class UILabel. I am declare here temporary.
    CGSize s = [yourlabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] // enter your text font size and  cell-width
                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourcellwidth, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                                 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    



    return s.height;    //this will give you height of UILabel view you can change using addition according your requirements
}
```

Hope, this will help you..